# Can I do something more with Pen.DashPattern?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, gdi+

So, I start from creating Pen using only Color as argument.
What can I do with DashPattern other that assigning a `float[]`?

I've tried to check if it is null or not, using comparison operator.
Result: `OutOfMemoryException`.

Checking length of potentially existing allocation also failed - same exception.

Problem started from trying to transfer data from a row of `float[,]` to DashPattern of Pen using `Buffer.BlockCopy()`.

Comment: The [Pen documentation for DashPattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.pen.dashpattern?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Pen_DashPattern) doesn't help? It includes sample code with not a single `Buffer.BlockCopy` in sight.

Comment: Is this correct at all? From documentation: "Gets or sets an array of custom dashes and spaces.". I can't or don't know how to get. I can only set. Always the same exception. I've done it "normal" way but still want to know where is my problem... There must be something i don't understand.

Comment: There's nothing to *get* until after something has been *set*. If there is no DashPattern set, you can't get it. There's nothing set.

Comment: This is something i understand. But why can't I check if it is null or not? Property just throws exception when i write something like: .DashPattern==null.

Comment: Don't know. I can't see your code.

Comment: Pen myPen  = new Pen(Color.White); if(myPen.DashPattern==null) {...}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is by design.

If you haven't specified a [DashStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.dashstyle) different from the default **`DashStyle.SolidColor`** or set the [Pen.DashPattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.pen.dashpattern) to a `float[]` value, setting, as a consequence, the [Pen.DashStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.pen.dashstyle) to **`DashStyle.Custom`**, the `Pen.DashPattern` is not set and the native **`GdipGetPenDashCount`** method will return a `Status != GDIP.Ok = 0`.

The default behavior, when the dash count is not set, is to raise a GDI+ exception, an **`OutOfMemoryException`** in this case.

What you can do is to test the Pen `DashStyle` and try to get its `DashPattern` only when `DashStyle != DashStyle.Solid` (setting this style explicitly won't create a `DashPattern`):

```
if (pen.DashStyle != DashStyle.Solid)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pen.DashStyle);
    pen.DashPattern.ToList().ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine(f));
}
```